# My tooltip width remains on fit-content without reaching the max-widht in parent container

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a component called Tooltip:

```
import { IProps } from "./type";
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "./style.module.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

const Tooltip = ({ text, position }: IProps) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleVisibility = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <Image
        src={"/icons/info.png"}
        width={24}
        height={24}
        alt=""
        onMouseEnter={handleVisibility}
        onMouseLeave={handleVisibility}
        className={styles.icon}
      />
      {visible ? (
        <p
          className={classNames(styles.content, {
            [styles.right]: position === "RIGHT",
          })}
        >
          {text}
        </p>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tooltip;
```

This is the CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-left: 4px;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  box-shadow: #000 1px 1px 1px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.content.right {
  right: 10px;
}

.icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The problem is when I have my tooltip inside a container `div or form` the width does not reach `400px`. However, if I test the Tooltip in isolation, it reaches that value.

### Examples:

```
  <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  width: "100%",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                }}
              >
                <Label
                  text="Nennleistung der Module"
                  htmlFor="location-2"
                />
                <Tooltip
                  text="Willkommen bei Tooltip!Ich bin ein KI-Sprachmodell, das Ihnen gerne bei Ihren Fragen und Anliegen weiterhilft.
Fragen Sie einfach nach, was Sie wissen möchten, und ich werde mein Bestes geben, um Ihnen zu antworten.
Vielen Dank für Ihre Nutzung und viel Spaß beim Chatten!"
                  position="RIGHT"
                />
              </div>
```

### Screenshot:

[image]

### Edit

After I tried `margin-right:-400px` on `right`, it adjusts too much to the right.

[image]

## Edit

If I set the `width:400px`, it works as I want, however, if the text is small the width remains fixed.

[image]

[image]

As you see when the text is short the width remains fixed on `400px`.

### Edit2

After @Temani afif comments, it works for right tooltip but the problem jump to the normal positions ( left ).

##### Changes

```css
.content.right {
  right: 10px;
  margin-left: -400px;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: add a big negative margin on the right `margin-right: -400px`

Comment: It adjusts the tooltip to the right too much.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, please check the edit section. I want the tooltip expand to the left when the position prop is RIGHT.

Comment: then negative margin-left

Comment: YES. it works when the position is RIGHT. 

BUT, the problem jumps to the normal position.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, please check the latest EDIT.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, It's fixed by adding `margin-right:0` to `right` class.